# Delphi, MySQL, ADOConnection - Converter dados do banco em latin1 para utf8

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8

Estou com problemas para converter as strings que vem do banco de dados (Mysql - latin1) para UTF8.

O caso é que preciso pegar os dados no banco codificando para UTF8 para gerar um XML com esse enconding.

Tentei algumas conversões para UTF8 depois de pegar os dados no banco mas nao funciona.

Acredito que eu tenha que já fazer a leitura da informação em UTF8. Alterando algo na ADOConnection ou na ADOQuery.

Alguém com experiência no assunto?

Não funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, já tive esse problema, a solução facil foi trocar o componente de conexão.

Hoje eu uso o `DBX` que também é nativo do Delphi assim como o que esta usando `ADO`.

Você também pode experimentar este aqui que não deixa nada a desejar [Componente Terceiro](https://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/?usingnationalcharacters.htm), de fácil uso, estou ate pensando em comprar uma versão melhorada dele da própria empresa desenvolvedora!

Você esta fazendo tudo certo, eu não uso `.AsWideString`, prefiro usar o `.AsString` mesmo, porem, acredito que no seu caso o resultado será o mesmo, o Correto é usar o UTF8Decode.

Todavia, defina um outro CharacterSet para seu banco caso não queira trocar de componente!

Aproveite e adicione na sua string de conexão (se usar claro) o `SET CHARACTER SET 'CP1251'`, talvez já seja um caminho!